# A hard Conformal Mapping problem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, conformal-geometry

I am trying to construct a conformal map from $R = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : -1 < Re(z) < 1$ and $Im{(z)} > 0\} \cap \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| > 1\}$ to the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$.  I am really am at a loss.  $R$ is symmetric about the imaginary axis, and it is bounded by three circles that need to be sent to the real axis.  I thought maybe we could think of the unit circle geodesic as a line with two points at infinity.  still no luck.  I would appreciate some help.  Thanks.

I was thinking maybe the map $f(z) = -z^{-1}$ sends everything to the half disk.  Does this look right?

Comment: It does… Then find a conformal mapping from the half disk to the disk.

Comment: That's funny.  I remember things being significantly more complicated than this in the discussion of the elliptic modular function.  The domain specified here is exactly that funny domain that we kept reflecting over circular arcs to iteratively construct the elliptic modular function.

Comment: I'm still a little iffy on showing it is surjective.  It is clear it surjects on the boundary of the upper half disk, and sends infinity to $0$, and $\{z \in R : Re(z) = 0\}$ onto $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : Re(z) = 0, 0 < Im(z) < 1\}$  From here how do I show it is onto the half disk?  Also clear it injects into half disk and is conformal on whatever the image is.

Comment: $1/z$ is not surjective from your domain to the half disk.  Okay, that's good.  I thought my memory was wrong. (For instance, it is actually a conformal equivalence with just the region where imaginary part is $>0$ and modulus is $>1$)

Comment: I'd like to add two points.  One is that the semidisk I meant above is the one below the real line.  The other is that you should be careful in your manipulation of generalized circles and circle segments.  The fact that you are discussing them suggests to me that you are looking for a very particular type of equivalence, the linear fractional transform.  But LFTs are conformal on all of the extended complex plane, so you cannot expect them to take your domain, which is bounded by 3 generalized circle segments to one which is bounded by 2.  With a general conformal map, you can.

Comment: (Take squaring for example on a quarter plane.)  Although all conformal maps of nice regions (regions bounded by a Jordan curve) also force the boundaries to correspond homeomorphically, it may be the case that they do not correspond in an angle preserving way even when that is a sensible statement.  To solve your question, I would recommend looking up a proof of the elliptic modular function to find the answer inside, but it is sort of a lot to do for just this small part of the proof.  Maybe someone who remembers the subject better has a better idea.

Comment: Use [Schwarz-Christoffel map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping) to map the rectangle to a half-plane, then map the half plane to the unit disk with a [Möbius Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation)

Comment: But it isn't a rectangle...

Comment: Its almost a rectangle with a half circle cutout, after transforming it will be a almost a circle with a small cutout, maybe this boundary will be easier to describe

Comment: My idea is to send the region $R$ to the upper half plane minus the closer of the disk.  Then inversion will give us a half disk (the lower half disk).  Can anyone think of a conformal  map to this region $S = \mathbb{H}$ \ $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$?